# Fill ship battle game board C

Tags: c, arrays, random

i was told to make a project of the shipbattle game with a 10x10 field. For now i need to know how to generate the ship's positions randomly in the field(which is a 10x10 array). The fields cannot be on top of each other and they cant be next to each other. they can also be in horizontal or vertical.

i need to place the following ships: 
1 ship of five fields
1 ship of four fields
2 ships of three fields
3 ships of two
4 ships of one

i'm not really seeing how i can do this. this is what i have so far:

```
void generateField(int field[][dim])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<dim; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<dim; j++)
        {
            field[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

this makes the field be all zeros. i want to generate the boats like i said before

Comment: Is it possible to place the first few ships such that the others have no space left? Then the assignment would be a little more challenging. Otherwise it boils down to placing them one by one. You will need a routine for collision testing. ("Given a boat of length l starting at x,y with orientation N,W,S or E, does it overlap or leave bounds or have a neighbour?") Then you iterate through your boats; choose candidate starting coordinates and directions randomly again and again until your routine says ok.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to have a method that will take an int (size_of_boat), and then pick a random number for `x` and `y` (let's say: 2,5).

all you need to do is check if you can fit that ship starting at that point.
1. Go left for size_of_boat. if you didn't find any other "occupied" bit, or you didn't step off the board. good.
2. if not, check up...
3. right ...
4. down ...

if you found a direction, set those bits in your array to true, and return true.
if not, it means you can't put a ship of that size in that position, so randomly search for another position and try again.

This is not the optimal algorithm, but i'm sure it's enough for your needs